# Can't compile a string in .Net 5 at Run Time

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5

I tried to compile a string but I got the error `System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Operation is not supported on this platform.'`

P.S:
I ran this code successfully in previous versions of .Net Core but in .Net 5 I faced this error and I found out that reading and compiling from files and strings is no longer supporting in .net 5

Now I'm looking for an alternative to compile my string and execute my code in Run Time and

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string sourceCode = @"
            public class SomeClass {
                public int Add42 (int parameter) {
                    return parameter += 42;
                }
            }";
        var compParms = new CompilerParameters
        {
            GenerateExecutable = false,
            GenerateInMemory = true
        };
        var csProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        CompilerResults compilerResults =
            csProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compParms, sourceCode);
        object typeInstance =
            compilerResults.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("SomeClass");
        MethodInfo mi = typeInstance.GetType().GetMethod("Add42");
        int methodOutput =
            (int)mi.Invoke(typeInstance, new object[] { 1 });
        textBox.Text = methodOutput.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: Could you show us the complete stack trace of the exception?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/may/net-core-cross-platform-code-generation-with-roslyn-and-net-core

Comment: System.CodeDom is not supported on .net5, there's [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/18768) about this problem. You can use alternatives based on roslyn, for example [this repo](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/cs-script)

Answer (score 4):

Short answer - `CompileAssemblyFromSource` is not supported in .NET Core or .NET 5.

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.compileassemblyfromsource?view=windowsdesktop-5.0#exceptions)

> **PlatformNotSupportedException**
>
> .NET Core and .NET 5+ only: In all cases.

There are alternative approaches (e.g. using [Roslyn](https://laurentkempe.com/2019/02/18/dynamically-compile-and-run-code-using-dotNET-Core-3.0/))

Comment: You're absolutely right! This answer should be marked as answer.

Comment: @RB. Yeah I'm aware of this and mentioned in my question that I'm looking for an alternative

Comment: Apologies - I didn't see that part. Question: Why are you not open to using Roslyn? It's pretty much *the* way of compiling code in .NET Core (I mean - it's literally a managed C# compiler...)? Other options might include shelling out to `csc.exe` and compiling that way, but that starts to get pretty ugly...